# jquery form selectors radiobutton and checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

hello i have a button inside a form

```
<tr>
    <td class="style2">
        gender
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="male" type="radio" checked="checked"/>m
        <input id="female" type=radio />f
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add a border to a radio button like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("form :input").css("border", "3px solid red");
    $("form :radio").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
```

And it`s not working, the radio buttons are not in border

Comment: are you trying to put a border around each radio button individually?

Comment: i agree with zspencer. You could want two things here. If you want to replace the default radio button with a circle with a red border, you are going to have to use my answer below. If you want a red border around the box the radio button is contained in, just wrap the inputs in a SPAN and style that with a border with basic CSS.

Comment: my code working for other inputs like: submit,text,file but not for radio button or checkboxs. can't i use the same for them olso , i want to see can i find my radio button or input type=radio by jquery and put it in a border to validate

Comment: so i think my question is can i use css tricks on radio button and checkboxs. thank you

Answer (score 2):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-radio-buttons/

Here is an articles with a workaround on how to customize radio buttons. You can't really achieve what you want with just pure CSS.

You are going to have to create an image (a checked and unchecked state) and use the above code to create your custom radio buttons

Here is another way to do it as well:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

**EDIT**

If you want the border to be a square border, and not a border around the circle button, refer to the answer below by Nathan Byers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the span element around your input elements. If you want just the radio buttons to be bordered use the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">gender
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="redBorder">
                <input id="male" type="radio" checked="checked" />
            </span>
                m

            <span class="redBorder">
                <input id="faemale" type="radio" />
            </span>
                f
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<script>
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(".redBorder").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
</script>
```